# Developing Client server application using INDY

Tags: delphi, indy

I am currently developing a client server app , but i want to clarify some information about the following.

What must be my idtcpserver binding IP adress (127.0.0.1 ,192.168.1.1 or my public IP)

> I checked it using IPconfig it replied me 192.168.1.1 ;but i have connected to the internet using my home adsl router(single port).

I have assigned my client application with

> idtcpclient.host := my public IP address

the application is working well when i assign both with 127.0.0.1 // as both are in the local machine

How to make my application work over the internet.When i try to connect over the internet the client is replying me

> Socket error #10061 connection refused.

but my kaspersky network monitor is showing that my port is opened my myapplication (I set it to 6000)

original project
[sourceforge](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=indy%20demos%20sourceforge&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/&ei=PbaiTsHeAsrTrQfdnrWnBA&usg=AFQjCNENXcLOhGq8vaXYger9DIbY7XAF1A)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a binding on the server machine.  Just assign the default port.  At run time, a single binding will be created with that port and a blank IP address.

When you connect to your network from the outside using the external IP address, you are actually connecting to your router (or other hardware).  You should be able to tell your router that traffic received on a specific port will be directed to an internal IP address.

I have a handful of servers running on my internal network, and this is how I make them available from the Internet.

You mention that you have a DLink router.  If it works the same as mine:

- Using your favourite web browser, open the router's settings page.
- I think the default address is http://192.168.0.1.  User name is "admin" with no password.
- Click the Advanced tab and select Virtual Server.
- The virtual server settings are pretty straight forward.

Comment: Is your PC connected directly to the Internet, or is it through a router or cable modem (for example) that acts as a router?

Comment: When you connect to that external IP address, you are actually connecting to your router.  You need to tell the router to redirect certain traffic to your PC's IP address.

Comment: My router is only having on pc ; how applications like skype work like this

Comment: Clients in your network can call out to the Internet with no problem.  Connecting to a PC in your network is a different matter, even if that network only has one computer.  I'll add details for changing your settings to my answer.

Comment: Binding to a specific network adapter IP address is not uncommon if there is more than one installed iiuc

Comment: @mjn: True, not uncommon if you have multiple nic cards, but not necessary otherwise and not related to the op's problem.