# Testing both INDY TCP Client and Server in same machine delphi

Tags: delphi, indy

I am building a basic client server application in delphi indy 10 ;

I have set sever app with local ip and a specific port, and i set client with public 
IP to client host when i am testing the application the following error i got
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859511/developing-client-server-application-using-indy)

I am testing both client and server app in same machine (as i had no other option),will this cause error.

Comment: Server and client will be fine on the same machine.

Comment: thanks but i am not sure when both application tries to open the same port

Comment: The server listens on the port. The client connects to the server on that port. No problem there. Has to be the same port otherwise they could not connect!

Comment: I think people are missing "I set server with LOCAL IP and client with PUBLIC IP". This is the same exact problem as in the other (linked) question; the asker doesn't know how to configure his server to be accessible from outside his local network. This is a server question, not a programming question, just like the other post.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely run a TCP client and server on the same computer.

Only one application can listen on a given port at a time, but (virtually) any number of clients can connect to that server, even from the same machine.

Did you find your router settings from the previous question?

Comment: Please detail what you've done in your other question.  As I said, I do this exact thing myself, so it should work for you.